# Create a matrix without definition of dimensions

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, tensors, matlab

is it possible to define a matrix **without** giving its dimensions in Mathematica,

e.g.

**First line:**

```
mattest[[1,2]] = 1;
```

**Second line:**

```
mattest[[4,2]] = 2;
```

....

***Error***

```
Set::noval: Symbol mattest in part assignment does not have an immediate value.
```

Such definition works in Matlab:

```
>> mattest(1,2)=1;
mattest(4,2)=2;
mattest

mattest =

     0     1
     0     0
     0     0
     0     2
```

Comment: A little clunky but if you make an empty list, you could use `append` or `prepend` to add the elements? You would need to write so it adds the empty lists before - `m={}` adding your first line would need `{ {}, {1} }`

Answer (score 8):

```
mattest = SparseArray@{{1, 2} -> 1, {4, 2} -> 2}

MatrixForm@mattest
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you just hate `SparseArray` without any reasonable reason, here's another possibility:

```
tomatrix[a_] := 
 Replace[DownValues@a, (_[a[i__]] :> v_) :> {i} -> v, {1}] // SparseArray // Normal

mattest[1, 2] = 1;
mattest[4, 2] = 2;

normalmat = tomatrix@mattest
(* {{0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 2}} *)
```

Notice in this case the generated matrix isn't stored in `mattest`.

Comment: Sparse matrix is not wished in this case, can we have other simple commands to define such matrix?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM Why is `SparseArray` not wished? It's simple enough in my view. You just don't like `{}` and `->`?

Comment: @a In the question you've clearly claimed that we should not give the dimensions of the matrix beforehand, while your `ConstantArray` method does. Still, you don't show a plausible reason for your dislike of `SparseArray`.

Comment: @a Sparse matrix is undoubtedly a matrix, its usage is just the same as the normal matrix AFAIK. Or you happen to run into any case that `SparseArray` doesn't work well? If so, please show an example.